# grep string where part matches condition 1 but another part does not match condition 2

Tags: grep

in a file like:

```
oneA twoA threeA
oneB twoB threeB
oneC threeC
oneA twoD threeA
```

how would I grep all lines containing `two` but not followed by `A`?

i.e.

```
oneB twoB threeB
oneA twoD threeA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#grep line containing two and exclude which has twoA
grep two filename.txt |grep -v twoA
oneB twoB threeB
oneA twoD threeA
```

Using Awk:

```
  awk '!/twoA/ && /two/' filename.txt
  oneB twoB threeB
  oneA twoD threeA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say:

```
$ grep 'two[^A]' file
oneB twoB threeB
oneA twoD threeA
```

That is, `grep` for `two` followed by any character apart from `A`.

Comment: this is nice as it could also be used when lines contain more than one occurrence of `two` to `grep 'twoA' file | grep -v two[^A]`. Say you wanted rows that have `twoA` but not any other `two`'s. Nice!

Comment: @threefrenchhens indeed! And you can also use `awk` and a nice trick --> `awk -F"twoA" 'NF==2' file`.